# Excel: IF-Statement copying and pasting into new cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

So I got a mastertable with 3 Rows and many entries: Combo | Number | Email

This was given to me, this is what I need to compare my search to. Now I've made another table else where. Imported a set of Combo I want to compare against the set in the master table. And made my table like this

Imported Combo | Is Imp.Combo in master table? | Number | Email

Imported Combo is being checked against Combo, if it is in there, it'll be true otherwise false.

What I need now is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/POxmA.png

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: I cleared up the question. Wasn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's still VLOOKUP (;

Suppose the values of your tables look like this:
"Mastertable" from A3 to C3 and "My own table" from E3 to H3

Check for match in F3

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E3,A3:A5,1,False)),"false","true")
```

Your formula for G3 would be the following:

```
=IF(F3="true",VLOOKUP(E3, A3:C5, 2, False),"-")
```

Your formula for H3 would be the following:

```
=IF(F3="true",VLOOKUP(E3, A3:C5, 3, False),"-")
```

HTH

Comment: still the same thing. (; Your true/false column is not necessary, you can do the whole trick with vlookup. I'll edit my answer in a minute.